# Specifc values over Axis in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot 3D graph where Y-axis has only values 9, 99 , 999. I tried to use

```
Y= [9, 99 , 999];
set(gca,'YTickLabel',Y);
set(gca,'YTick',Y);
```

I want to have 3 points 9 at the beginning, 99 in the middle, and 999 at the end. Is it possible to do that?. I tried also with Ylim, but couldn't help

[image]

Comment: Try `set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')`

Comment: I tried it along with ylim([9 999]); , and the above code, and it works. Add it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `y`-axis to a logarithmic scale.
Use:

```
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
```

If you also set

```
ylim([9 999]);
```

as you had pointed out, you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
F = [1 2 3];
Y = [9, 99 , 999];
Y_ = [9, (999-99)/2 , 999];

figure; 
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(Y,F,'*-');
set(gca,'XTickLabel',Y,'XTick',Y);
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(Y_,F,'o-');
set(gca,'XTickLabel',Y,'XTick',Y_);
```

You can see the difference:

[image]

Comment: If you apply that on a graph 3D for example using surf(x,y,z). The result isn't right because there is a value on Y= 99 , and if I make tick on (999-99)/2 in that case the value of 99 will be shown , but won't match the tick on Y axis which in that case (999-99)/2.

Comment: Did you take into account that for better generalization I am using the X-axis instead of the Y-axis?